# Issue Code Coverage for Maven MultiModule Project

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

Currently we are trying to get code coverage for multi-level module maven project . Below is the snippet of the same

```
parent
 - child1
   - sub-child1
   - sub-child2
 - child2
   - sub-child1
   - sub-child2
pom.xml
```

We have used the Jacoco plugin and tried generating the code coverage but it down't seem to be generating any jacoco executable file .

Any guidance over the same would be really helpful

Tried referring and executing the same 
https://github.com/acntech/jacoco-multimodule-maven

```
<properties>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent-for-it</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I expect the jacoco plugin to generate a single exe file and push the results to sonarqube